# Design Question for ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm a newbie to the ROR world and I'm trying to use ActiveAdmin to design the Admin Panel for an Artists Portfolio Website.
The idea is that each artist has a login/password and can manage assets.

The models are set with has_many in the AdminUser table, and belongs_to in the linked models.
For example, an AdminUser has_many Videos.
There are many linked assets.

What would be the best approach so that:

- The currently logged in AdminUser only has access to his own assets?
- The currently logged in AdminUser is set as the admin_user_id field
  for each newluyy created asset?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this answer is in time.

Q1. The currently logged in AdminUser only has access to his own assets.

A1. use cancan for your authorization framework. By default ActiveAdmin doesn't provide the authorization ability for you.  so , the key code may looks like:

```
# in your app/models/ability.rb
class Ability 
  include CanCan::Ability
  def initialize(user)
    can :read, Asset, :admin_user_id => user.id
  end
end
```

for more detailed steps of using Cancan (very easy, you can deal with it in 15 minutes ), please refer to : https://github.com/ryanb/cancan

Q2. The currently logged in AdminUser is set as the admin_user_id field for each newluyy created asset.

A2: AdminUser is just a "User" model. so, you can call it "current_user" in your view and controller as the regular Devise's way. e.g.

```
#in your controller
def create_xx
  # save the admin_user_id to the newly created asset.
  Asset.create(:admin_user_id => current_user.id)
end
```

for more details of Devise, see its official website: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise